# Define operator for List in C#

Tags: c#, matrix, operator-keyword

I would like to define some operations for List in C#.
For example, addition (+) and transpose(').
However, errors appeared when I compiled the code.
I defined a matrix class which is inherited from List>.
Moreover, I implemented the + and ' operator.
The first one is good but when I called it in the main, errors appear.
The second method cannot be even compiled. 
Can anyone please help?
Thanks a lot.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Matrix : List<List<double>>
    {
        public static Matrix operator +(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            Matrix c = new Matrix();
            int i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < a[1].Count; j++)
                {
                    c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
                }

            }

            return c;

        }


        public static Matrix operator ' (Matrix a)
        {
            Matrix b = new Matrix();
            int i, j;

            for (i = 0; i<a.Count; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < a[1].Count; j++)
                {
                 b[j][i] = a[j][i];
                }

            }

            return b;

        }


        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {

            Matrix x = new Matrix { new List<double> { 1, 2, 5, 2 }, new List<double> { 3, 4, 0, 7 } };
            Matrix y = new Matrix { new List<double> { 1, 2, 5, 2 }, new List<double> { 3, 4, 0, 7 } };
            Matrix z = new Matrix();

            z = x + y;

            Console.WriteLine(z);

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just choose to "overload" any arbitrary symbol you want. There is no such operator as `'`

Comment: What errors do you get? What is the exact issue you're having?

Comment: Here is a list of overload-able operators  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28VS.71%29.aspx

Here is the tutorital for overloading operators - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: You don't allocate any space for your new matrix c.

Answer (score 1):

' is not a valid operator. The overloadable operators are:
Unary: + - ! ~ ++ -- true false
Binary: + - * / % & | ^ << >> == != < > <= >=

Some of these also have restrictions. For instance, the comparison operators must be overloaded in pairs and the second parameter of the shift operators (<< and >>) must be an `int`.

Take a look at: [C# overloadable operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Comment: OK, let's ignore the ' method first. How to correct the errors in "+ "?

Comment: What are the problems in 

Matrix x = new Matrix { new List<double> { 1, 2, 5, 2 }, new List<double> { 3, 4, 0, 7 } };
            Matrix y = new Matrix { new List<double> { 1, 2, 5, 2 }, new List<double> { 3, 4, 0, 7 } };
            Matrix z = new Matrix();

            z = x + y;

Comment: @Frankie `Matrix c = new Matrix();` will create an empty Matrix. It contains no inner lists. That's why you will get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on the line `c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];`

Comment: I changed it to:

            Matrix x = new Matrix { new List<double> { 1, 2, 5, 2 }, new List<double> { 3, 4, 0, 7 } };
            Matrix y = new Matrix { new List<double> { 1, 2, 5, 2 }, new List<double> { 3, 4, 0, 7 } };
            Matrix z = new Matrix { new List<double> { 1, 2, 5, 2 }, new List<double> { 3, 4, 0, 7 } };

            z = x + y;

But the error also occurs

Comment: `Matrix z = new ...` is completely useless. You're giving z another value in the next line. Just make it `Matrix z = x + y;` But the problem is in the operator+ method.

Comment: You need to add all the lists to the Matrix c first: `int size = a[0].Count; for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++) { c.Add(new List<double>(size)); for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { c[i].Add(0); } }`